# Discord Bot Commands not working with on_message

Tags: python, discord.py, command

I have a few commands that worked perfectly, but when I add on_message they don't. I read that you need to add the await bot.process_commands(message) line, but it still doesn't work for me. Why?

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == 'prefix':
        prefix = guilds.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})["prefix"]
        await message.channel.send(f"> The prefix for this server is: {prefix}")
    else:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function ends as soon as it encounters a `return` statement, with your current logic it will only process the commands if the `if` statement is `True`. Simply remove that `else` part.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == 'prefix':
        prefix = guilds.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})["prefix"]
        await message.channel.send(f"> The prefix for this server is: {prefix}")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm just a bit... stupid.. XD

Answer (score 0):

The `await bot.process_commands(message)` code is only reachable when the message content is 'prefix'. To fix that put the `await bot.process_commands(message)` in the else body:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == 'prefix':
        prefix = guilds.find_one({"_id": message.guild.id})["prefix"]
        await message.channel.send(f"> The prefix for this server is: {prefix}")
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```